# How can I "Page Down" from the keyboard in an Apple Mail message list?

Tags: mail.app, macos

With recent versions of Apple Mail, the Page Down key always applies to the message content pane (unless no message is selected), even if the message list had focus. However, you used to be able to type Control–Page Down to make it apply to the message list. This no longer works in OS X 10.9. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [some AppleScripts](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2013/10/30/message-list-page-down-in-mavericks-apple-mail/) that can Page Up/Down in Mail’s message list, and the scripts can be assigned Control–Page Up/Down as keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Command-Option Down-Arrow seems to do it for me

Comment: ⌘⌥↓ seems to go to the bottom for me, instead of the next page.

Comment: Yes, that's like the End key except that it changes the selection. I'm looking to scroll down one page without changing the selection.

Answer (score -1):

fn + down arrow seems to work on yosemite

Comment: It scrolls the message content not the message list for me